# Regex in notepad++ for sql

Tags: sql

Need help with regular expression for this in Notepad++:

```
INSERT INTO Table (S,SN,SNM,ID,U,G,Gr,Hu,Huv,Date,IDt,B) 
 VALUES ('2007', '94920', 'Text','9492','Text','949',''Text,'94','Text;    
  r','2001-01-01',0,CONCAT(1,1)
```

I want to replace value 1,1 with value '2007','94920' How can I solve it in a regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're talking about editing within Notepad++ using RegEx search/replace functions. In which case:

1. CTRL + F
2. Click on the Replace tab
3. In the 'Search Mode' box below, select 'Regular expression'
4. In the 'Find what' bar type the following RegEx: 1\,1
5. In the 'Replace with' bar type the following: '2007','94920'
6. Replace/Replace All

Tried it myself and worked. Hope this helps.